# Why is matchesKeyInQuery is returning all results, not just those of the current user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

A fiddle can be found here. The results should be only badge 5 is returned not badge 8.

Trying to use the  `matchesKeyInQuery`to achieve the following:
1 - Return results only for the current user only
2 - Only return results for the current user where the `B_Notify` column equals "Unread"
3 - Include access to columns "SentTo and "uploadedBy"

At the moment, the below query doesn't seem limited to just the current user as all results are being returned.

Also, I cannot get the query to work unless I repeat 'SentTo" in the `NotificationTwo.matchesKeyInQuery`query

Can someone show me what I've done wrong, or how to correct it please?

```
                var NotificationOne = new Parse.Query("myBadges");
                NotificationOne.equalTo("B_Notify", "Unread");   

                 var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

                var NotificationTwo = new Parse.Query("myBadges");
                NotificationTwo.include('SentTo', currentUser);
                NotificationTwo.include('uploadedBy');

                NotificationTwo.matchesKeyInQuery("SentTo", "SentTo", NotificationOne);

                NotificationTwo.find({
```

[image]

Comment: I thought there is a typo. It should be `NotificationTwo.equalTo('SentTo', currentUser')` and also forgot the statement NotificationTwo.include('SentTo').

Comment: @eth3lbert where abouts?

Comment: @eth3lbert I think its the current user part thats not working, as all results seem to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the query you gave, I thought it could be rewrite as following:

```
var notificationQuery = new Parse.Query('myBadges');
notificationQuery.equalTo('B_Notify', 'Unread');
notificationQuery.equalTo('SentTo', Parse.User.current());
notificationQuery.include(['SentTo', 'uploadedBy']);
notificationQuery.find({ ...
```